# How to define a library runtime location in Xcode4?

Tags: xcode4

In my Cocoa application I'm using a third party C-library that is compiled in command line and available in a custom location.

In my Xcode project I can define where the library's header files are located and where the library is looked during linking:

Header files location (`HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS`):

```
Target > Build Settings > Search Paths > Header Search Paths
```

Library location during linking (`LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS`):

```
Target > Build Settings > Search Paths > Library Search Paths
```

But how do I define the library's runtime location ? At the moment when I run my Cocoa application in Xcode (`cmd-r`) I get an error from dynamic linker:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libfoo.1.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

My application runs without problems when I create directory `/usr/local/lib` and a symbolic link to the library.

`man dydl` tells about three related environment variables:

- `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`
- `DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH`
- `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH`

I know how to set the variables on a bash terminal (see e.g. [Where do I set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH on Mac OS X, and is it a good idea?](https://superuser.com/questions/282450/where-do-i-set-dyld-library-path-on-mac-os-x-and-is-it-a-good-idea)), but how do I set environment variables for Xcode ?

I'm running OS X 10.8.x and Xcode 4.5.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Xcode 4.5 *a scheme* specifies the executable environment (including environment variables) when a target is launched.

See chapter [Build and Run Your App](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/055-Build_and_Run_Your_App/build_app.html) in [Xcode 4 User Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide) for the details of schemes.